# How to create a macro using "type nul > filename.txt"?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to create a simple macro using the windows command line which creates first a directory and then a file in that directory.

As an example, if the command was my_macro I would type  "my_macro directory file.txt" and it would create a directory called "directory" with file.txt in it.

the command right now is:

```
doskey doer = mkdir $1$tcd $1$t(type nul > $2)
```

The only part that doesn't work is the creation of the file (i.e type nul)

Comment: ">" should be `$g`.

Comment: What you're defining here is a console alias. When CMD calls `ReadConsoleW` to read from the console, the console host (conhost.exe) implements a simple line editor that supports input history (e.g. up/down arrows and F7 popup) and aliases that match at the beginning of a line. So, when you type `doer spam eggs.txt`, what CMD reads from the console is `mkdir spam & cd spam & (type nul > eggs.txt)`. It's only when reading from the console and only matches at the beginning of a line. So we can't use an alias in a batch script or pipe to it.

Comment: Create a batch that does that, put the batch file into a directory that is on the `PATH` - I have one dedicated directory where I put all those little batch files and that is always part of the PATH